# Mongoengine : Why to_json return $oid or $date key ?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, mongoengine

Using python and mongodb with mongoengine, I wonder why "to_json" function doesn't work as excepted.

For exemple,with "Comments" as a Document, comments.**to_json()** returns me :

```
  {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "53eb97a312f8035580b92241"
  },
  "created": {
    "$date": 1407955862027
  }
```

And I except to get :

```
  {
  "_id":"53eb97a312f8035580b92241",
  "created": 1407955862027
  }
```

Do I really need to parse all the json data to get what I want ?

Answer (score 2):

JSON supports simple datatypes only and as such there is no native JSON support for ObjectId's or for dates. [BSON](http://bsonspec.org) the binary json supertype that MongoDB stores its data in has support for more datatypes.

To allow lossless BSON -> JSON -> BSON conversion there is an [extended json format](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) and this is what MongoEngine uses.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response. It's clear now ! I gonna parse my json data.

Comment: I also think what your asking for isnt unreasonable - maybe there should be a per Document override or setting to make it easier.  It would be worth adding an issue to the project..